# Deployed my react app to github, but homepage is blank

Tags: reactjs, github, react-router

After I deployed my react app on Github, and it works. However, it only shows the navigation. Not sure how to explain, please check this pic: [Homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBqNu.png)

After I click on the navigation, everything works fine. [Here](https://rongbangye.github.io/mini-react.js-projects/) is the Github deployed page.
Here is the [Github page](https://github.com/rongbangye/mini-react.js-projects).

Answer (score 0):

Check the default landing URL, and if `<Route />` used, check if any component is rendered for that particular path. This path will be an exact match, so check for trailing '/' etc.

Your landing URL is https://rongbangye.github.io/mini-react.js-projects/, but there might be no component matched for that path.

Also reload on your site is giving a 404 for which you might need to look in to webpack configuration (if used). Changing webpack publicPath might help.

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: '/',
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the process.env.PUBLIC_URL in the routing root. BrowserRouter comes with a props called basename which allows you to define the base Url for the project. It would be like this.

In your App.js, `<Route exact path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/'} component={Home} />` 
replace with:

```
<BrowserRouter history={history} basename= . {process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    </Switch>
   </BrowserRouter>
```